# Magento add Two Discount Rows in Quote Section

Tags: php, magento

I am working on one project where we are using followup emails to retarget clients by email in cart. what we are doing we are sending emails with user cart and 10% discount.

so when user click on link we activate user abundant cart with more discount of 10%. if user using couponcode we add 10% amount in his couponcode.

what we want to show discount but what we are giving 10% extra we want to show in new row. what means

Couponcode Discount  Amount
Extra 10% Discount   Amount

that means discount comes in two rows. if user not using couponcode we just discount one row
Extra 10% Discount  Amount

please if someone has idea please let me know...

Here is code i am using.

[code]

```
if($discountAmount>0) {
$total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
$quote->setSubtotal(0);
$quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

$quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
$quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

$quote->setGrandTotal(0);
$quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);`enter code here`
$canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual()? ('billing') : ('shipping');
foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
$address->setSubtotal(0);
$address->setBaseSubtotal(0);
$address->setGrandTotal(0);
$address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);
$address->collectTotals();
$quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
$quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());
$quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
(float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
);
$quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
(float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
);
$quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
$quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());
$quote ->save();
$quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal())
->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal())
->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal())
->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal())
->save();
if($address->getAddressType()==$canAddItems) {
//echo $address->setDiscountAmount; exit;
$address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
$address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
$address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
$address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
if($address->getDiscountDescription()){
$address->setDiscountAmount(-($address->getDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
$address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription().', Custom Discount');
$address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
}else {
$address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
$address->setDiscountDescription('Custom Discount');
$address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
}
$address->save();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setspecialURLdiscount('updated');
// header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
}
} //end: foreach
}
}
```

[/code]

Comment: Try the code.  If you have a problem when implementing it, post it.  Not kind to ask us to code something for you.  Also, as someone who works for a marketer, be wary of training your customers to shop, leave, and wait for the added discount... they may not know how to use a semicolon, but they do know how to save $$!

Comment: Nice that you've updated your code (/me prays for indentation to be a law of the land).  Now that you've shown what you've tried... what worked?  What didn't?  Give us a description of where things are so that we can pinpoint the best area for help.

Comment: in this code discount added or update very good. but i want to add one more row under discount name ( Email Discount ). i don't want to add extra discount i want to show in new column.

Comment: u want only description of discount applied to cart to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question, below information may help you.

In class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` you can set Discount Description .

In the function

`public function process(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)`

go down to the following line.

`$discountAmount = $result->getDiscountAmount();`

and place the following 2 lines after above code which will prepare our description array in current foreach loop

```
$_formatedDiscountAmount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($discountAmount, true, false);
$_descriptionArray[] = $rule->getName()."-".$_formatedDiscountAmount;
```

and at last, right after the end of the array place this code

```
$address->setDiscountDescriptionArray($_descriptionArray);
```

In `$_descriptionArray` array you can have your discount description.